# How to get enabled custom keyboard name from settings programatically

Tags: java, android, keyboard

In my app I have a custom keyboard and now I need to detect, to know is my app's custom keyboard is enable or not in settings. like [Kii  keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zl.inputmethod.latin&hl=en) app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the InputMethodManager and list enabled input methods:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
String list = im.getEnabledInputMethodList().toString();
```